# Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017, connection attempt failed: SocketException: Error connecting to 127.0.0.1:27

Tags: mongodb

I want to change the default port of mongodb so I did :

sudo nano /etc/mongod.conf

```
# network interfaces
net:
  port: 27042
  bindIp: 127.0.0.1
```

and

```
sudo service mongod start
```

But now when I want to run "mongo" I got this error:

```
MongoDB shell version v4.0.24
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/?gssapiServiceName=mongodb
2021-05-18T12:44:36.436+0200 E QUERY    [js] Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017, connection attempt failed: SocketException: Error connecting to 127.0.0.1:27017 :: caused by :: Connection refused :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:356:17
@(connect):2:6
exception: connect failed
```

The message says " couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017" despite I changed the port in mongod.conf. I even tried to reboot my computer but it still not working.

UFW is not active si I don't think it's a firewall problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your `mongod.conf` file, MongoDB will run on port 27042. When you run the command `mongo`  without parameter `--port`, it will connect to the default port 27017 then you have the error.

I think this command `mongo --port 27042` will work.

Comment: is there any way to configure mongo and run it on 27042 by default without specify the "--27042" each time I need it ?

Comment: There are 2 different things: `service mongod start` is the command to run the MongoDB server. `mongo` is the command to connect to the MongoDB server. The `mongo` command **always** needs the param `--port` if you use a non-default port. You can put this command in a script to facilitate if you want.